# How can I improve speed and efficiency of my VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

**I'm trying to build an Excel workbook to automate and aid in the creation of a weekly work schedule.**

My current workbook is functional, but it's slow - especially on one task where I have a list of people with an annual schedule that I'm searching two sheets at the same time.

***I think there's a better and more efficient way than the one I'm using***.

```
Option Explicit

'Global variable that will be in another module where I store all general config

Public Const PlanningAgentEmptyRange        As String = "C12:G58,F74:G78" 'Range agent present
Public Const PosteWeekDayRange               As String = "B12:B72" 'Range agent present
Public Const PosteWeekEndRange               As String = "B73:B78" 'Range agent present


Sub DraftFromCycle()

    'If range is empty (to prevent the lost of approved schedule)
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(PlanningAgentEmptyRange)) = 0 Then

        'list of day/col Weekday in weekly schedule
        Dim aWeekDay(1 To 5) As String
        aWeekDay(1) = "C": aWeekDay(2) = "D": aWeekDay(3) = "E": aWeekDay(4) = "F": aWeekDay(5) = "G"

        'List of day/col weekEnd in weekly schedule
        Dim aWeekEnd(1 To 2) As String
        aWeekEnd(1) = "F": aWeekEnd(2) = "G"

        Dim DayDate As Range
        Dim cel As Range
        Dim Col As Variant
        Dim DayRangeCycle As Range
        Dim DayCycleCol As String
        Dim DayCycleRow As Integer
        Dim AgentName
        Dim p, s, poste, x As Variant
        Dim Cycle_lastrow As Integer
        Dim Cycle_lastcol As String


        Cycle_lastrow = LastRow(Feuil55)
        Cycle_lastcol = lastCol(Feuil55)


        'Loop col/Day  of weekday
        For Each Col In aWeekDay

            Set DayDate = Range(Col & "11")
            Set s = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A5:OA5").Find(What:=DayDate, Lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not s Is Nothing Then
                DayCycleCol = ColLetter(s.Column)

                For Each poste In Worksheets("Cycle").Range(DayCycleCol & "6:" & DayCycleCol & Cycle_lastrow)

                    Select Case poste
                    Case Is = "AM"
                        Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).Find(What:="Après-midi", Lookat:=xlWhole)
                        If Not x Is Nothing Then
                            Do
                                If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row) = "" Then
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.row).value
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row).Font.Italic = True
                                End If
                                Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).FindNext(x)
                            Loop While Not x Is Nothing
                        End If

                    Case Is = "N"
                        Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).Find(What:="Nuit", Lookat:=xlWhole)
                        If Not x Is Nothing Then
                            Do
                                If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row) = "" Then
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.row).value
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row).Font.Italic = True
                                End If
                                Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).FindNext(x)
                            Loop While Not x Is Nothing
                        End If

                    Case Is = "R N"
                        Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).Find(What:="Récup Nuit", Lookat:=xlWhole)
                        If Not x Is Nothing Then
                            Do
                                If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row) = "" Then
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.row).value
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row).Font.Italic = True
                                End If
                                Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).FindNext(x)
                            Loop While Not x Is Nothing
                        End If

                    Case Is = "R Av"
                        Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).Find(What:="R.H. Avant Garde", Lookat:=xlWhole)
                        If Not x Is Nothing Then
                            Do
                                If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row) = "" Then
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.row).value
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row).Font.Italic = True
                                End If
                                Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).FindNext(x)
                            Loop While Not x Is Nothing
                        End If

                    Case Is = "R Ap"
                        Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).Find(What:="R.H. Après Garde", Lookat:=xlWhole)
                        If Not x Is Nothing Then
                            Do
                                If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row) = "" Then
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.row).value
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row).Font.Italic = True
                                End If
                                Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).FindNext(x)
                            Loop While Not x Is Nothing
                        End If

                    Case Is = "RTP"
                        Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).Find(What:="R.T.P.", Lookat:=xlWhole)
                        If Not x Is Nothing Then
                            Do
                                If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row) = "" Then
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.row).value
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row).Font.Italic = True
                                End If
                                Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).FindNext(x)
                            Loop While Not x Is Nothing
                        End If

                    Case Else
                    End Select

                Next poste
            End If
        Next Col

        'Loop col du Week End
        For Each Col In aWeekEnd

            Set DayDate = Range(Col & "73")
            Set s = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A5:OA5").Find(What:=DayDate, Lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not s Is Nothing Then
                DayCycleCol = ColLetter(s.Column)

                For Each poste In Worksheets("Cycle").Range(DayCycleCol & "6:" & DayCycleCol & Cycle_lastrow)

                    Select Case poste
                    Case Is = "AM"
                        Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekEndRange).Find(What:="Après-midi", Lookat:=xlWhole)
                        If Not x Is Nothing Then
                            Do
                                If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row) = "" Then
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.row).value
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row).Font.Italic = True
                                End If
                                Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekEndRange).FindNext(x)
                            Loop While Not x Is Nothing
                        End If

                    Case Is = "N"
                        Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekEndRange).Find(What:="Nuit", Lookat:=xlWhole)
                        If Not x Is Nothing Then
                            Do
                                If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row) = "" Then
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.row).value
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row).Font.Italic = True
                                End If
                                Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekEndRange).FindNext(x)
                            Loop While Not x Is Nothing
                        End If

                    Case Is = "6h25"
                        Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekEndRange).Find(What:="6h25 - 13h25", Lookat:=xlWhole)
                        If Not x Is Nothing Then
                            Do
                                If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row) = "" Then
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.row).value
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row).Font.Italic = True
                                End If
                                Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekEndRange).FindNext(x)
                            Loop While Not x Is Nothing
                        End If

                    Case Is = "7h30"
                        Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekEndRange).Find(What:="7h30 - 14h30", Lookat:=xlWhole)
                        If Not x Is Nothing Then
                            Do
                                If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row) = "" Then
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.row).value
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row).Font.Italic = True
                                End If
                                Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekEndRange).FindNext(x)
                            Loop While Not x Is Nothing
                        End If

                    Case Is = "7h45"
                        Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekEndRange).Find(What:="7h45 - 14h45", Lookat:=xlWhole)
                        If Not x Is Nothing Then
                            Do
                                If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row) = "" Then
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.row).value
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.row).Font.Italic = True
                                End If
                                Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekEndRange).FindNext(x)
                            Loop While Not x Is Nothing
                        End If

                    Case Else
                    End Select

                Next poste
            End If
        Next Col

    End If
End Sub
```

Here's a screen of what the sheets look like
the module take the data from the annual schedule and autofilled the weekly schedule if it's empty

**Annual Schedule (Worksheets("Cycle"))** 
[image: Annual Schedule (Worksheets("Cycle")]

**Weekly Schedule (Worksheets("1"))**
[image: Weekly Schedule (Worksheets("1")]

Comment: You might want to start by using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = False`. That said this might be better suited to the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hi, i tried using those but then the whole workbook is not responding. Thanks for the link i'll take a look

Comment: "not responding" means VBA is busy running your code; even the most efficient code can make Excel "not responding" while it's running. Don't take "not responding" as an indication of anything. That said, your code can probably be made more efficient indeed, but that's a job for [codereview.se] - protip: you'll want to use a post title that describes the purpose of the code, because everybody there wants to "change their code to make it run smoother" ;-)

Comment: `Dim p, s, poste, x` - These are all Variants. Try Dimming them as what they actually are?

Comment: Without the Application.ScreenUpdating and EnableEvents = False the code take 60 sec to run with them i only tried to wait 10 min but after that i killed excel. I added the dim as Variant

Comment: If your code works, and you're just looking to have it improved, your question should be asked on [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: Please fix your indenting before asking for review

Comment: @Jmeyer  You turned off Application.ScreenUpdating and EnableEvents and then the script took 10 minutes or did you forget to turn them back on?

Comment: Yeah it was to late sorry, as suggested i moved the whole thing to Code Review : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/203210/automating-the-creation-of-weekly-schedule
@Jerry Jeremiah yes i did turn them back on it didn't work for some reason. But now with all of Comintern suggestion it works

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question has been moved by OP to code review